# Paypal doDirectPayment: INVNUM vs OrderId, AMT vs OrderTotal

Tags: paypal

I was improving my payment process, and I realized that the documentation now didn't matched my code ( by extention, the documentation I had when I wrote that code ).

If I compare that page:
https://cms.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/?&cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_soap_r_DoDirectPayment

To this page:
https://cms.paypal.com/ca/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_api_nvp_r_DoDirectPayment

The variables names are not the same.

Is AMT an alias for OrderTotal ?
Is INVNUM an alias for InvoiceId ?

BTW; Are variable names case sensitive ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One is SOAP, and the other were NVP.